# Error While Saving Order Data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I created one module for bank transfer which will collect data from customer. This is working fine when i placed an order. But when i edit an order from admin and try to add comments to order then it is giving below error message.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception): Request does not match any route.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception): Request does not match any route.
#0 /var/www/html/b2b/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(83): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Router->match(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/b2b/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(68): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->checkPermissions()
#2 /var/www/html/b2b/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(86): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator->validate()
#3 /var/www/html/b2b/app/code/Ibnab/Additional/Observer/SaveBankInfoToOrderObserver.php(21): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()
```

Here is the complete code of my observer .

```
<?php
namespace Ibnab\Additional\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Banktransfer;
class SaveBankInfoToOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_inputParamsResolver;
    protected $_quoteRepository;
    protected $logger;
    protected $_state;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver $inputParamsResolver, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
        $this->_inputParamsResolver = $inputParamsResolver;
        $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_state = $state;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {
        $inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();
        if($this->_state->getAreaCode() != \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML){
        foreach ($inputParams as $inputParam) {
            if ($inputParam instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment) {
                $paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');
                $paymentOrder = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
                $order = $paymentOrder->getOrder();
                $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
                $paymentQuote = $quote->getPayment();
                $method = $paymentQuote->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

                if ($method == Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE) {
                    if(isset($paymentData['bankowner'])){
                    $paymentQuote->setData('bankowner', $paymentData['bankowner']);
                    $paymentOrder->setData('bankowner', $paymentData['bankowner']);
                    }
                    if(isset($paymentData['banknumber'])){
                    $paymentQuote->setData('banknumber', $paymentData['banknumber']);
                    $paymentOrder->setData('banknumber', $paymentData['banknumber']);
                    }
                    if(isset($paymentData['banktransid'])){
                    $paymentQuote->setData('banktransid', $paymentData['banktransid']);
                    $paymentOrder->setData('banktransid', $paymentData['banktransid']);
                    }
                    if(isset($paymentData['bankname'])){
                    $paymentQuote->setData('bankname', $paymentData['bankname']);
                    $paymentOrder->setData('bankname', $paymentData['bankname']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

       // print_r($paymentQuote);exit;
       }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me on how to resolve this error?

Comment: error happens before or after you save the edit?

Comment: I am calling above observer on sales_order_payment_save_before

Comment: the error is about the webapi route

Comment: yes but i didn't created any web_api.xml file. can i create one?

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_payment_save_before">
        <observer name="save_bank_infos" instance="Ibnab\Additional\Observer\SaveBankInfoToOrderObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>

Comment: i have events.xml as above

Comment: Can you suggest me some solution plz?

Comment: wait let mecheck

Comment: https://github.com/ibnab/payment-additional , I taken this module and added my additional fields to the payment page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93129/discussion-between-dinesh-and-magefms).

Comment: Try moving `$inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: if (strpos($current_url,'vorders') !== true) {
        $inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve(); } I tried like this but no use. same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error due using **Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver**.

Please update your Observer code as follows

**step 1:**

Update **SaveBankInfoToOrderObserver.php** file code as given below.

File:***/app/code/Ibnab/Additional/Observer/SaveBankInfoToOrderObserver.php***

```
<?php
namespace Ibnab\Additional\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Banktransfer;



class SaveBankInfoToOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_inputParamsResolver;
    protected $_quoteRepository;
    protected $logger;
    protected $_state;
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver $inputParamsResolver,
     \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
      \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
      \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
      ) {
        $this->_inputParamsResolver = $inputParamsResolver;
        $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_state = $state;
         $this->_request = $request;
    }


       public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {        
         $route      = $this->_request->getRouteName();          
        if($route ==''){ 
        $inputParams = $this->_inputParamsResolver->resolve();        
        if($this->_state->getAreaCode() != \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML){
        foreach ($inputParams as $inputParam) {
            if ($inputParam instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment) {
                $paymentData = $inputParam->getData('additional_data');
                $paymentOrder = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
                $order = $paymentOrder->getOrder();
                $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
                $paymentQuote = $quote->getPayment();
                $method = $paymentQuote->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
                if ($method == Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE) {
                    if(isset($paymentData['bankowner'])){
                    $paymentQuote->setData('bankowner', $paymentData['bankowner']);
                    $paymentOrder->setData('bankowner', $paymentData['bankowner']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       }
      }

    }
```

}

**Step 2:** Run DI compile

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Now you can cancel order from Frontend and backend without getting any error.

Comment: Hi Pritam , Your code is working and thank you very much

Comment: Hi Dinesh. It's my pleasure.

Comment: Hi Pritam , have you worked on tax? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273134/how-to-get-shipping-tax-class-in-magento2... can you please help me on this.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to move the **events.xml** file

from

**app/code/Ibnab/Additional/etc/**

to

***app/code/Ibnab/Additional/etc/frontend/***

So the event observer observes event for frontend only.

Comment: I tried this code , it is working for backend. In frontend when customer wants to cancel an order it is giving error. Any other solution?

Comment: Are you getting the same error (i.e. Request does not match any route)? when canceling an order from the frontend

Comment: yes getting same error when i cancel order from frontend customer.

Comment: Please check my 2nd answer.